# flutter_sound not recording any voice

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I need to record voice and send it with `Firebase`. I am using `flutter_sound` but the plugin doesn't generate a recorded file and I don't know why.

```
Future<String> result =flutterSound.startRecorder(null,androidEncoder: AndroidEncoder.AMR_WB);

result.then((value){
    print('startRecorder: $value');
    _recorderSubscription = flutterSound.onRecorderStateChanged.listen((e) {
    DateTime date = new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(e.currentPosition.toInt());
    String txt = DateFormat('mm:ss:SS', 'en_US').format(date);
    print(txt);
    });
});
```